# How to find specific images which start with a string in Swift Assets.xcassets

Tags: swift, xcode, image, bundle, assets

I am developing a swift application and need to find some images which start with a specific string,  but i dont know how to find that images from Assets.xcassets.

All of the my images is in the Assets.xcassets

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to name the assets like star1, star2, star3. Then using a for loop to load an image for "star\(x)" and x can be the variable in the for loop. They can be added to an array of UIImages and then accessed.

Comment: My aim is to find the names of the images which start with starx. How to loop all images in the Assets.xcassets folder to find that images

Comment: It should work I'll post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assets folder cannot be accessed this way. One way to do that is creating a folder with all the images on your computer, and drag into the Xcode project. Dont forget to select the "Create folder references for any added folders" option. With that referenced folder, you can access all images:

```
guard let _resourcePath = Bundle.main.resourcePath else{
        return
    }
    do{
        if let url = NSURL(string: _resourcePath)?.appendingPathComponent("YOUR FOLDER NAME"){
            let resourcesContent = try FileManager().contentsOfDirectory(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)

            for imageUrl in resourcesContent {
                let imageName = imageUrl.lastPathComponent
                print(imageName)
                //CHECK IMAGE NAME STRING
            }
        }
    }catch let error{
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should name the images you want with the identifier at the start. I will use the word star for an example.

The images should have names like star1,star2,star3,star4 and so forth. This code should work.

```
var imagesCollected = [UIImage]()

for n in 1 ... 10{ //10 is whatever number you want
    let imageloaded = UIImage(named: "star\(n)")
    imagesCollected.append(imageloaded)
}
```

The `imagesCollected` should have all your images. Let me know if that works.

Niall

Comment: Thank you Niall for the answer, but it will not work for my case, because the names of my images don't continue with number after the keyword(star in our example).Think that i have the images, animals_cat.png, animals_bird.png, animals_lion.png, etc.. Here "animals" is my category name. I want to find all the images which belong to specific category (like "animals"). The only thing i know is the category name. Nothing else. If i loop over all the images on Assets.xcassets then i can find them.

Comment: Ok, don't know what you can do if you don't change the names. Sorry I can't help

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the names of the images yourself? I mean do you load the images into the Assets.xcassets manually yourself or do you add them programatically? 
If you do, you could create a dictionary and add image names either manually in code or programatically every time an image is added to the Assetts.xcassets.

imageDict = [category:[animalType]] for a 2D dict. 
Access it as follows

```
import UIKit

var NaturePicsDict: [String : [String]] = ["cats":["Lion", "Tiger", "Panther"],
                                          "Birds": ["Hawk", "Parrot", "Sparrow", "Blackbird"]
                                          ]

//create an array of animal names for each category and then construct the full image file name from the category:animal using string concatination.

var animalsForCategory:[String] = []

for category in NaturePicsDict.keys {
    print("key = \(category) animal =" ,NaturePicsDict[category]!)
    let animals = NaturePicsDict[category]!
    for animalName in animals {
        let imageName: String = "\(category)_\(animalName)"
        print("imageName = \(imageName)")
    }
}
```

sorry about all the edits. I am learning how to use this site. Anyway, the output from my code snippet is:

```
key = cats animal = ["Lion", "Tiger", "Panther"]
imageName = cats_Lion
imageName = cats_Tiger
imageName = cats_Panther
key = Birds animal = ["Hawk", "Parrot", "Sparrow", "Blackbird"]
imageName = Birds_Hawk
imageName = Birds_Parrot
imageName = Birds_Sparrow
imageName = Birds_Blackbird
```

Hope this helps. I have just been using a 3D dictionary in an app I'm writing and have found it a very compact way of storing and accessing drill down info.

Comment: Thank you Ali for the answer, but it will not help me. Becuse the only thing i know about the images is their category name. I think the answer of @João Pedro Morais looks like acceptable.